# Regular Expression-Image Name containing specific word

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I have list of article images which name include some word by which we can indentfy image type (front image,back image etc).These all expression will be database table .I need to getlist of expression from database table than validate image name with regular expression.

```
type                         word                   Expression
Frontimage                   _front
Left image                   _left
Right image                  _right
Top image                    _top
Bottom image                 _bottom
Rear image                   _rear
```

I need regular expression which identify these from image name so that I can decide which image is which type.

Example: A123450_front is front image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex looks for a `_` character as an anchor and extracts the following information.

```
string text = "A1_23450_front";

string pattern = @"(_[^_]+)";  

Regex.Match(text, pattern, RegexOptions.RightToLeft).Captures[0].Value;
```

Result is the *word* `_front`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . But if I will only search front word than what would be Regex because it might be possible articlenumber can also have _ character .

Comment: @Rakesh are there any other hidden specifications which have not been listed? The post only lists one example, why not provide others examples which will most likely occur in the ream of operations?

Comment: @Rakesh updated the answer to handle multiple occurrences of `_`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32023954/how-to-find-word-in-string-using-regular-expression