# How to find word in string using regular expression

Tags: regex

How to find word in string using regular expression regardless of case sensitivity ?

Exmaple:

1. `A1234_front123`  in this need to find _front word
2. `a1235Front1234yy` in this I need to find front

I need to design generic regular expression which can find any kind of words in given string

Comment: When you say any kind of word, do you mean any correct english word, or just any combination of letters, not including numbers? Or do you mean "front" specifically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If front could be another word, this should try with such combination:

```
(?<=[0-9])[A-Za-z_]+(?=[0-9_])
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zW2jH3/1)

it will work without case insensitive mode `i`

Answer (score 0):

You must use `i` modifier.

```
/front/i
```

Online example: https://regex101.com/r/hQ9hH6/1